# Initialize vector without copying and using move semantics

Tags: c++, c++17

Is there a way to avoid copying when initializing a vector?

The code below will produce the following output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Ticker {
    std::string m_ticker;
    
    Ticker() {
        std::cout << "Default constructor" << std::endl;
        }
    Ticker(const std::string& ticker) 
    : m_ticker(ticker)
    {
        std::cout << "Parametrized constructor" << std::endl;
    }
    Ticker(Ticker&& other) 
    {
        std::cout << "Move constructor" << std::endl;
        m_ticker = other.m_ticker;
        other.m_ticker = "";
    }
    Ticker(const Ticker& x) 
    {
        std::cout << "Copy constructor" << std::endl;
        m_ticker = x.m_ticker;
    }
    ~Ticker() 
    {
    std::cout << "Destructor" << std::endl;
    }
    
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Ticker& dr);
};

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Ticker& dr)
{
  os << "|" << dr.m_ticker << "|";
   return os;
}
    

int main() {
  std::vector<Ticker> table = std::move(std::vector<Ticker>{std::move(Ticker("MSFT")), std::move(Ticker("TSL"))});
  for (const auto& row: table)
  {
    std::cout << row << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
Parametrized constructor
Move constructor
Parametrized constructor
Move constructor
Copy constructor
Copy constructor
Destructor
Destructor
Destructor
Destructor
|MSFT|
|TSL|
Destructor
Destructor
```

Is there a way to avoid the copy constructor and initialize in-place or just move without copying?

Comment: I would recommend not just brute-force guessing with c++. It's a bit to complicated to get right. Try to understand how things works instead. All the `std::move`s in your code are redundant as they are applied to rvalues.

Comment: In case you don't actually need the vector for anything else and just want to loop over a fixed set of elements you could also just use an initializer_list, e.g. `for(auto const& row : {Ticker{"MSFT"}, Ticker{"TSL"}}) { /* something */ }` [godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/ezG73dz4M)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you use

```
std::vector<Ticker> table = std::vector<Ticker>{Ticker("MSFT"), Ticker("TSL")};
```

You will get

```
Parametrized constructor
Parametrized constructor
Copy constructor
Copy constructor
Destructor
Destructor
|MSFT|
|TSL|
Destructor
Destructor
```

Which has 4 constructor calls instead of the 6 you currently have.  2 of those calls are for `Ticker("MSFT")` and `Ticker("TSL")` and then the additional two copies are because initializer lists store the elements in them as `const`, so they have to be copied into the vector as you can't move from a `const` object.

To get the bare minimum of 2 constructor calls you'll need to use the [`emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) member function like

```
std::vector<Ticker> table;      // create empty vector
table.reserve(2);               // allocate space for 2 Tickers but create nothing
table.emplace_back("MSFT");     // directly construct from "MSFT" in the reserved space
table.emplace_back("TSL");      // directly construct from "TSL" in the reserved space
```

which has the output of

```
Parametrized constructor
Parametrized constructor
|MSFT|
|TSL|
Destructor
Destructor
```

If you want a syntax like `std::vector<Ticker> table = std::vector<Ticker>{Ticker("MSFT"), Ticker("TSL")};`, but without the extra overhead, you could wrap the `emplace_back` solution in a factory function like

```
template <typename T, typename... Args> 
auto make_vector(Args&&... args)
{
    std::vector<T> data;
    data.reserve(sizeof...(Args));
    (data.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args)), ...);
    return data;
}
```

and then you would use it like

```
auto table = make_vector<Ticker>("MSFT", "TSL");
```

Comment: yea that is what I would use if I wanted to avoid the copy (emplace_back), I wanted to have the nicer syntax of the initializer lists, but I guess that's the only solution.

Comment: @BlueTrin You could abstract that ugliness away like this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c7b2acbdbf0aad90

Comment: @BlueTrin No problem, glad to help.  I added the method into the answer just in case the link ever dies.

Comment: That is quite ingenious IMO, though I also recommend a primer on [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold), as that's something relatively new, and *definitely* not seen very often.